# Simulate file download with Gatling

Tags: http, gatling

Good morning,

I would like to simulate a file download with Gatling. I'm not sure that a simple `get` request on a file ressource really simulate it:

`val stuffDownload: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Download stuff")
    .exec(http("Download stuff").get("https://stuff.pdf")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/force-download"))`

I want to challenge my server with multiple downloads within the same moment and I need to be sure I have the right method to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**EDIT**: Other headers I send:

```
"User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36",
"Accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
"Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language" -> "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
"DNT" -> "1",
"Connection" -> "keep-alive"
```

Comment: It's impossible to say whether your method is right if you don't include your method in your question

Comment: Hello @DanFarrell, sorry for not including the method the first time, I thought it was too trivial to mention it. Anyway, post edited. Cheers

Comment: I just added more lines in my request. I feel it may help simulating my action with more accuracy... but yet, I'm not sure it's 100% ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks technically globally fine except that:

- you have 2 Content-Type ?
- Is there a mistake in second one ?
- Also aren't you missing other browser headers like User-Agent ?
- Aren't you missing an important one related to Compression like Accept-Encoding ?

But regarding functional part, aren't you missing some steps before it ? 
I mean do your user access immediately the link or do they hit a login screen , then do a search and finally click on a link ?

Also, is it always the same file ? Shouldn't you introduce a kind of variability using Gatling CSV Feeders for example with a set of files ?

Comment: Thank you for you insight. I've corrected my test, choosing only one Content-Type. User-Agent and Accept-Encoding are defined earlier in my test, I will update my post. 
Login page and authentication are handled but I removed those steps from my post to give a SSCCE :) 
And yes, it is always the same file, it's a generated document users have to download.